# Visual Studio/CLR: Is it possible to watch an unmanaged pointer's attributes?

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, clr, unmanaged

**COMMON LANGUAGE RUNTIME**

Is there any way to "watch" - see the member variables/values - an unmanaged pointer in a Visual Studio debug watch window in a VB.NET <=> Managed C++ <=> Unmanaged C++ hierarchy?

For example:

**C++**

```
  public ref class MyManagedCPP_Class
  {
    private:
      MyUnmanagedCPP_Class *myUnmanagedPtr;
                
    public:
      MyManagedCPP_Class() { <set up myUnmanagedPtr etc> }
      ...
  }
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim myVBVar as MyManagedCPP_Class
<myVBVar initializations etc>
<break and interrogate the unmanaged pointer>
```

I would like to see the values in *myUnmanagedPtr in the watch window, but cannot get past e.g.

```
myUnmanagedPtr = &H10BF9C28.
```

I've tried various casting combinations and permutations within the watch window, but either it cannot be done, or, I have not yet worked out the correct way. Is it because the unmanaged pointer is [by definition] outside of the CLR and consequently, VS2019 does not understand `MyUnmanagedCPP_Class` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Is it a Visual Studio bug?

Comment: Hello @MinxinYu-MSFT: Thanks for taking a look. Appreciated. Hmmm...interesting. I shall pursue my enquiries...

Comment: By the way, I can only see `*m.myUnmanagedPtr {myUnmanaged} myUnmanaged`
, and can't see its members such as int A. Try testing in VS2022 if it produces the same problem.